# Get task start time and task duration

Tags: python, celery

The celery worker is reporting:

```
[2015-09-29 16:13:50,411: INFO/MainProcess] Task xxx.tasks.tasks.process_files[e91db27d-9d16-487f-acae-d6966205ba16] succeeded in 52.9951906s: None
```

From my client, I can access some task info:

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult

task_id = 'e91db27d-9d16-487f-acae-d6966205ba16'
res = AsyncResult(task_id)
print(res.state)
print(res.info)
```

I would also like to know:

1. When was the task triggered?
2. How long did it take to complete?

Can I access this information from the `AsyncResult`? I see nothing in the [documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult).